# Setting "col sep = semicolon"

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, csv

I obtain this table:

[image]

using this code:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
col sep = comma,
string replace*={_}{\textsubscript},
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
display columns/0/.style={string type,column name={}}
]
{Workbook1.csv}
```

Probably because my `col sep` is not `comma`, but `semicolon`. But if I code `col sep = semicolon` I obtain this:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '< 1' as a floating point numbe
r, sorry. The unreadable part was near '< 1'..

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.79 {Workbook1.csv}
```

How can I code `col sep = semicolon` without any error?

Answer (score 4):

Isn't the error quote clear? `<1` is tried to be interpreted as a number, which it obviously is not. If you do the same for the inequality columns that you have done for the first column, settings it as a text column, this will work. You may want to use math mode, in which case you can define a new column type and use that.

I don't know what you want to do with the header row, below I added `header=false`, so that the first row contains the index unless `column name` is defined.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{M}{>{$}c<{$}}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
col sep = semicolon,
header=false,
string replace*={_}{\textsubscript},
every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
display columns/0/.style={string type,column name={}},
display columns/2/.style={string type,column name={},column type={M}}
]
{
A-C-Pr;31;<1;27.3
F-C-Pr;31;<1;27.3
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ok thanks, and how can I do if I would display all the columns with column type M?

Comment: @Stefano Do you really want that? Move the `column type={M}` outside the style definition for the second column.